# Future Technology Devices International communication

Tags: serial-port, ftdi

Will FTDI always converts the data into serial or any other types of transfers?

Answer (score 0):

> Will FTDI always converts the data into serial or any other types of
> transfers?

Answer to your question in short. FTDI chips implements USB protocol stack that is serial.

The FTDI cable is a USB to Serial (TTL level) converter which allows for a simple way to connect TTL interface devices to USB. The VCC pins of this FTDI cable are configured to operate at 5V with 3.3V I/O.

---

## What happens inside the USB?

USB micro controller inside which talks a proprietary protocol over USB (hence the need for drivers) and converts that into "normal" UART signals and back again.